# Django Unicode method is not working

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am following the app tutorial on the Django website and using Python 2.7.5 with Django 1.8. It suggests users to include a unicode method in the models.py file to return readable output in the python shell.

I have added the unicode method into the Question and Choice classes as so:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%i" % self.question_text

    def __str__(self):
        return question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%i" % self.choice_text

    def __str__(self):
        return choice_text
```

This is my output from the python shell:

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: Question object>]
```

When it really should be this:

```
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: What's up?>]
```

I have asked this question before but have not found a solution. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the django unicode compatible with python 2 and 3 use the python_2_unicode_compatible decorator. Then use `__str__` for the unicodes:

```py
from django.utils import encoding

@encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.question_text
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use both `__unicode__` and `__str__`. In Python 2.7 you just have to use `__str__` . You can remove the `__unicode__` and just use `__str__` alone. `__unicode__` is for python 3.

Read more about it in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__)

Comment: I believe it is the other way around. In Py2 there are `__str__` and `__unicode__`, while on Py3 there is only `__str__`. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods